# What is the relation of Client and Server in a Blazor Web App

Tags: blazor

In A Blazor Web Application I may have a service on the server called say "TestService"- and lets say it has a pubic method called "TestMethod".

In one of my client side razor pages I can have a button like so:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OnTest">Test</button>
```

and this OnTest method can call the server side service like so and it will pass back the (in this case bool) result:

```
bool result = testService.TestMethod()
```

So, the client has called the server and the server has responded to the client.

My question is, in a Blazor web app like this, does the server in any way maintain a record of that client, so that it could send a message to it at a furture time?

The more general question would be:

Is there a way and if so what is the simplest way of being able to send messages to specific (or all) of the clients that the service (or server side Blazor app) has ever heard from?

Comment: You should look into SignalR, WebSockets, and SSE. Blazor is a RAD platform that allows people to write (honestly, rather bloated, IMHO) WASM-based SPAs without needing a real understanding of modern JavaScript, so it feels like we're repeating the mistakes WebForms made back in 2001.

Comment: WASM or Server?